# how to send url in bluesnap to remove subscription?

Tags: php, curl, payment-gateway, bluesnap

I am php developer, I integrate my site with bluesnap. I want to allow user to remove their subscription. Bt I cannot pass url from curl, bt "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden....." arrise ?

Here is the code

```
$xmlToSend = ' < subscription xmlns="http://ws.plimus.com" >< /subscription ' > ';               
$url = 'https://ws.bluesnap.com/services/2/subscriptions/'.$subs_id;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/xml')); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $credentials);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlToSend);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);

curl_close($ch);
```

how to solve this? Can I did this from another way or how to get another solution with out curl lib?

Thanks

Comment: Any one can help me? plz come forward.... other alternative is also accepted

Answer (score 0):

$xmlToSend =
        `<subscription xmlns="http://ws.plimus.com">
        <subscription-id>' . $subscription_id . '</subscription-id>
        <status>C</status>
        <underlying-sku-id>' . $skuId . '</underlying-sku-id>
        <shopper-id>' . $shopper_id . '</shopper-id>
        </subscription>`;
This xml format i am using for cancelling the subscription
$url = 'https://ws.bluesnap.com/services/2/subscriptions/'.$subs_id;
you need to to modify the xml not the link, link is correct.
please check the link [here](http://docs.bluesnap.com/api/services/subscriptions/retrieve-subscription)

Answer (score 0):

**Http error 403** error typically means - you do not have the Access roles or IP address enabled/needed to access the service - you need to reach out to support to grant relevant roles for the subscriptions you are coding for. i see that you are calling subscriptions - you need appropriate roles enabled for that call; also you may want to look into calling the cancel subscription API if you wish to [cancel the subscription](http://docs.bluesnap.com/api/services/subscriptions/update-subscription#update-subscription-status-cancelactivate-subscription)